# Automake - how to keep the source tree clean?

Tags: builds

I have a project that uses GNU autotools to build itself. I am trying to modify so that autotools generates all the non-versioned control files in a separate directory so that I can keep the source tree clean of temporary files. Anyone has any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: Just do a out-of-tree build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311231/store-gnu-make-generated-files-elsewhere it still leaves some residue, unfortunately. Give CMake a try some day.

Comment: That day has come, it took me less than an hour to switch from that ugly autconf to cmake which seems a lot more cleaner.

Comment: CMake is way cleaner than autoconf: in fact, a out of tree build is the most common way of doing a CMake build. Good choice :)

Comment: How usual is it to have a Makefile at the top of the source tree that controls the build process with cmake? Say **make** will run **mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make** and so on (different targets maybe like **make test** etc.).

Comment: Uncommon. CMake should generate makefiles, not the other way around! Look for a book called Mastering CMake or at VTK or KDE building processes for real word examples. A great advantage of CMake is being on top of make: it can also build your software using Visual Studio vcproj, nmake Makefiles, XCode etc. KDE uses a shell script ('kdebuild') to start the build processes - maybe you want to take a look at it.

Comment: Maybe put your comment as an answer Vitor?

Answer (score 3):

The autotools package has a lot of hard coded relative paths and names in it for a good reason. Your best option is to sum up the output and tag them as ignored in your revision control, e.g. in `.cvsignore`, `.hgignore` or as `svn:ignore` attibute. Some RCS let you even recursively specify wildcards.

Comment: There is not a single good reason to have this hard coded relative paths other then this is 1970ths unix programming style.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution: make an out-of-source build

- As suggested in comments, you can do an out-of-source build.
- The principle is: create another directory, a "build tree", run configure script from that directory (with relative or absolute path).

## Example with automated check

For example, this will fetch and build GNU hello and check that the source tree is not changed a tiny bit.

### Source tree preparation

This part fetches and prepares the directories.

```
{
wget -S http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.10.tar.gz
tar zxvf hello-2.10.tar.gz
mv hello-2.10 hello-2.10-pristine
tar zxvf hello-2.10.tar.gz
diff -urq hello-2.10 hello-2.10-pristine && echo "Before build, directories are identical."
cd hello-2.10
}
```

### Generic part: reuse that in your project

This part can be used with other autoconf-based projects. Just cd into your project before running.  Beware: this runs `rm`, if playing with variants be careful, you are reponsible in any case.

```
export MYPREFIX="${PWD}.installtree"
(
set -eu # abort on error
ls configure # make sure it aborts if not in correct directory
export SRCTREE="${PWD}"
export BUILDTREE="${PWD}.buildtree"
rm -rf "$BUILDTREE" "$MYPREFIX"
mkdir "$BUILDTREE" "$MYPREFIX"
cd "$BUILDTREE"
"${SRCTREE}"/configure --prefix="${MYPREFIX?}"
time make -k || time make
time make install
)
```

### Check part

This checks if build is perfectly out-of-source.

```
{
ls "$MYPREFIX"/bin/hello && echo "Okay, build generated the target."
cd "$MYPREFIX"/..
diff -urq hello-2.10 hello-2.10-pristine && echo "No change at all. Perfect out-of-source build success."
}
```

Here it outputs this:

```
/tmp/hello-2.10.installtree/bin/hello
Okay, build generated the target.
No change at all. Perfect out-of-source build success.
```

### Bonus: non-root install

The `--prefix="${MYPREFIX?}"` part above is optional. It allows to do a "make install" that is local to your account.  If you want traditional "sudo make install" to system-wide location, you can remove `--prefix="${MYPREFIX?}"`.